# Access Team Foundation Server (TFS) for non-AD users

Tags: tfs, active-directory

We have recently installed TFS 2010.  Our Active Directory users (i.e. my company's staff) can access it just fine.

However, we also have contractors working in the office who do not have an AD account.  I am having difficulty trying to get the non-AD users to connect to TFS through Visual Studio.  The contractors are on the same LAN but have no AD account, which we do to restrict access to other resources on the network.

I created local Windows user accounts on the server for the contractors.  With the local account they can access the TFS web front end but still cannot connect through Visual Studio.

Is there any way to do this?  Do the contractors need to have Remote Desktop access to the server itself?

Comment: I found that I can get this working without using AD for contractors. Add the users as local windows accounts with the "Access this computer from the network" option enabled in Local Security Policy > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment.

Comment: Our organisation was unwilling to give AD access to external staff due to security considerations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely give your contractors AD accounts. If you want to restrict access to internal resources, you can use Organisational Units in AD, like

- MyCompany

  - Employees
  - Contractors

And set access restrictions to your resources according to groups linked to the OUs.

Giving remote access to the server will just create another set of issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - now that I know what the right thing is I need to go persuade my manager.

Answer (score -1):

When you install a non Express version of TFS, you need an AD for authentication, you can't use properly the TFS server from a non AD account.

From this point you have two solutions:

1. Create AD account for contractors (one per company or one per user, your call).
2. Create a domain Trust between your domain and the contractor's one. See [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253081.aspx) for more info.

I don't understand clearly the Remote Desktop part, explain please.

Comment: The RDP part was a red herring I think.  I was trying to connect to the server using the contractors account.

Comment: What's your source for this comment:  "When you install a non Express version of TFS, you need an AD for authentication"

Comment: I really wonder who could put a -1 on this comment. I've installed more TFS server in companies that I can remember and you have two modes: Windows Account which is now the Express version limited to 5 account max (setup account included), or AD where you can only set AD based account to the permissions. I'm just trying to help people here, that's all...

Comment: I've installed full TFS 2010 in an environment that does not have an AD infrastructure, by creating local users on the host machine.  When you connect, you are prompted for username and password (which is then cached for you).  Could you provide info to the contrary?

Comment: Ok, let me sum up by this statement: don't mix workgroup and AD accounts in your TFS installation. And that were the purpose of the question rf_wilson asked: AD account for company people and workgroup for contractors. You can deploy TFS with workgroup accounts only, it works, you won't have the full features of a complex deployment but it doesn't matter because workgroup was designed for "developer enthusiasts". You can use Workgroup only deployment with more than five account if you own a Standard TFS license, but I never saw such deployment.

Comment: If you want info about that, please read the blog of Brian Harry.